# Bind Exe and Dll and set execution path

Tags: dll, exe, bind

I have one exe which depends on one dll file for auto startup . I want to bind my exe and dll file and set their execution path and want one another exe file as a result.

When user click on exe then my origional exe and dll should execute to my specific path.

I tried many EXE binders but they were malicious .I want clean Binder.

Kindly suggest me way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

go to run in windows,
type iexpress,
go through the installation GUI,
add the exe and the DLL file you want to bind.
your new exe will be ready.